# Kendo UI Chart automatic tooltip position

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, tooltip, kendo-dataviz

Does Kendo UI chart have automatic tool-tip position that detects if it is outside the containing box it will reorient the tool-tip to other position so that it will stay inside the containing box?

In my case the tool-tip was oriented to the right, but when I hover the right most data item, the tool-tip become obstructed by the containing box.

Unfortunately if I move my mouse to scroll the chart to see the tool-tip, the tool-tip would auto hide it self.

I know that the solution might just have the tool-tip auto hide disabled. But hey maybe there is an automatic tool-tip position somewhere???

Kendo Chart screenshot 1
[image]

Kendo Chart screenshot 2
[image]